# Change name of linux server on network

Tags: linux, networking, hostname

I'm using CentOS 5.  How do I change the hostname of the machine so I can ssh to it from other boxes by a short hostname?  I've tried "hostname puppet", changing "/etc/sysconfig/network" and "sysctl kernel.hostname=puppet".  I'd like to be able to do this without making changes to any hostfiles.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have to setup a local DNS server or you will have to change hostfiles. The changes you did will work, only to be identified in the local system and not from other systems.

Comment: So it won't work with a basic home router?

Comment: I can hit my Mac from another computer by typing in "ping haddad-desktop".  Why would this work and not the changes on the linux box?

Comment: It might be doing so with the help of NETBIOS/WINS thing. I am not too much into windows to explain that.

Comment: I rebooted the box after changing "/etc/sysconfig/network" and it seems to be working.  I also did the sysctl command, so I'm not sure which one would have done it.

Comment: Ugh.  Nevermind.  Seems domain.local is a MacOS X only thing.

Comment: `.local` is mDNS, which is implemented for Linux as **avahi-daemon**

Comment: mDNS is a proprietary Apple protocol. The fact it is implemented in Avahi does not change that. And it hijacks the ".local" TLD (which is not delegated to Apple).

Answer (score 1):

no need to reboot

1   /etc/hosts

2   /etc/sysconfig/network

3   /bin/hostname

$su -c service syslog restart

logout

login